# PHP: How to change search behaviour of include/require function?

Tags: php

Standard include or require function first of all looking for an included file in directories set in include_path variable. After that it searches the file in the current directory.

```
// Standard behaviour
inlcude "needed_file.php";

// 1. Looking for in include_path directories
// ...
// 2. Looking for in the current directories
// ...
```

But is it possible to implement the reverse behaviour: first of all look at current dir, and after that into dir in include_path variable?

```
// Necessary behaviour
inlcude "needed_file.php";

// 1. Looking for in the current directories
// ...
// 2. Looking for in include_path directories
// ...
```

I can write a script that do this task like that:

```
function include_file_inverted( $filename ) {
  // Looking for a file in the curret dir
  if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . $filename)) {
     include (dirname(__FILE__) . $filename);
  } else {
     // Looking for a file in the include_path
     include $filename;
  }
}
```

But are there another posibilities to invert search behaviour of include function?

**UPDATE**

Instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` it is necessary to use `getcwd()`. Because the function can be described in other included file.

```
// This function is described in ./admin/ directory, 
// but it is called from other places.
function include_file_inverted( $filename ) {
  // Looking for a file in the curret dir
  if (file_exists(getcwd() . $filename)) {
     include (getcwd() . $filename);
  } else {
     // Looking for a file in the include_path
     include $filename;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I slightly change my question.

If the needed file is absent in the current directory and it is only in the include_path, the last file should be called.

```
// Main working script try to include needed file
include "the_needed_file.php";

// It is located in the included_path and is called from where.
/{included_path}/the_needed_file.php
```

If the needed file is in the current directory, it does something and after that it should include file with the same name in the included_path directory.

```
// Main working script try to include needed file
include "the_needed_file.php";

// the_needed_file is in the current directory.
// {current_dir}/the_needed_file.php
<?
  // It does something
  // ...

  // And it includes file from a system directory decribed in include_path

  // When I write this code
  include "the_needed_file.php";
  // it recursively calls the current file. It is an error.

  // So I need to write something like that
  include "/{included_path}/the_needed_file.php";
?>
```

Any suggestion how to improve this code?

Comment: `set_include_path('.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());`

Comment: just use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @Tschallacka Not `__DIR__` not `dirname(__FILE__)`, only `getcwd()`. See update.

Comment: @IvanZ it depends where the file is located. Is it located to your current executing file or relative to your current include file. If you wish to include a "brother" file that resides in the same directory as the file you're running the include from or a subdirectory then you will want to use `__DIR__` it all depends on use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is it possible to implement the reverse behaviour: first of all look at current dir, and after that into dir in include_path variable?

*Make* the current dir the first one in the list of directories this setting contains.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path:

> Using a . in the include path allows for relative includes as it means the current directory.

The default value for this setting is `.;/path/to/php/pear`, so that would search the current directory first already. (On a unix system, the separator is `:` instead of `;`)

If you need this on systems where you don’t know the configuration up-front, check if the first entry is a `.`, and if not, add it. (You might want to make sure it doesn’t occur again later in the list, so as to not have the same directory searched twice.)

get_include_path and set_include_path can be used, or ini_get and ini_set.

Comment: Excelent. This work! Adding a point '.' in include_path do what I want.